# Django form error message showing despite selecting something from dropdown

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django model which is:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)
```

I'd like to create a form where user can select an existing account's phone number from a dropdown list. So in `forms.py`, I have:

```
class AccountSelectForm(forms.Form):
    phone_num_err_msgs = {'required': "You must select a phone number to send this message."}

    phone_number = forms.CharField(required=True, error_messages=phone_num_err_msgs)
    selected_group_ids = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    launch_datetime = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

In `views.py`, I have:

```
class AccountSelectView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'campaigns/send.html'
    form_class = AccountSelectForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('campaigns:taskq_list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(AccountSelectView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['groups'] = Group.objects.all()
        data['campaign'] = Campaign.objects.get(id=self.request.GET['cam_id'])
        data['accounts'] = Account.objects.all()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # If we insert pdb, we never reach here
        #import pdb
        #pdb.set_trace()

        data = form.cleaned_data
        campaign_id = self.request.GET['cam_id']
        # ... do other form validation stuff here
        return super(ConversationSendView, self).form_valid(form)
```

In `send.html`, I have:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- A couple of other fields to collect user input -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>Step 3: Select aphone number to send the message FROM:</b></p>
        {{ form.phone_number.errors }}
        <select id="phone" style="width: 380px;">
            <option value="">--------</option>
            {% for a in accounts %}
                <option value="{{ a.id }}">{{ a.number }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    <div class="page-btns">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message to Selected Group(s)" />
    </div>
</form>
```

But despite selecting the entry from the dropdown list (and all other required forms) before submitting, I keep seeing the `phone_num_err_msgs` on the HTML page  [[please see the screenshot here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNISA.jpg).

Is there something that I'm missing? Where (which file) can I import `pdb` and see why it is returning an error? I'm new to Django, so this is very likely a silly mistake/overlook. Thanks in advanced for the answers!

Comment: From this reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.error_messages, your validation never gets called, so maybe you should override the `clean_phone_number(self)` and do some logic to ensure the phone number provided is a valid one. BTW, note that the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.required indicates the form fields are mandatory by default.

Comment: @sgmart, Thank you for the reply. I found the problem per Daniel's suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here. The immediate cause is that you are missing `name="phone_number "` in your select tag, so the browser is not sending any data for that element.

But it is not clear why you are constructing that element manually anyway. Rather than defining a CharField and ignoring it, you should be using a ModelChoiceField, which will automatically give you a select box with all the accounts in.

```
class AccountSelectForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    phone_number = forms. ModelChoiceField(queryset=Account.objects.all())
```

...

```
{{ form.phone_number.errors }}
{{ form.phone_number }}
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding "name" attribute in my select tag solves the problem. :) I am not familiar with ModelChoiceField, but seems like a cleaner/easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. I'll give it a try once I get home this evening. Thank you so much again.